Proving $x-x=0x^2$ in a wheel.
According to Approach0, this is new to MSE.
My previous two questions on wheels are:

Proving $0x+0y=0xy$ in a wheel.
Proving $x/x=1+0x/x$ in a wheel.

They are inspired by the Wikipedia page.
The Question:

Let $W$ be a wheel. Prove that $$x-x=0x^2$$ for all $x\in W$.

The Definition:
A wheel is an algebraic structure $(W,0,1,+,\cdot, /)$ where:

$W$ is a set,
$0,1\in W,$
$+$ and $\cdot$ are binary operations,
$/$ is a unary operation,

and

$+,\cdot$ are associative, commutative, and with identities $0$ and $1$, respectively,
$//x=x$,
$/(xy)=/x/y$,
$xz+yz=(x+y)z+0z$,
$(x+yz)/y=x/y+z+0y$,
$0\cdot 0=0$,
$(x+0y)z=xz+0y$,
$/(x+0y)=/x+0y$,
$0/0+x=0/0$.

We denote $0/0$ by $\bot$.
The final axiom can be written as
$$\bot+x=\bot.$$
Thoughts:
I'm not sure I understand subtraction in this context, so here is the definition according to the Wikipedia page ibid.:

the negation $−x$ is defined by $−x=ax$ and $x−y=x+(−y)$ if there is an element $a$ such that $1+a=0$ (thus in the general case $x−x\neq 0$).

That said, it looks like the axiom
$$xz+yz=(x+y)z+0z$$
will be of most use here.
If I let $z\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto /x$ with $y\mapsto-/x$ (if $-/x$ even exists), then
$$x^2/x-x^2/x=(/x-/x)x^2+0x^2.\tag{1}$$
Now associativity gives
$$x(x/x)-x(x/x)=(/x-/x)x^2+0x^2.$$
Substitute in $x/x=1+0x/x$:
$$x(1+0x/x)-x(1+0x/x)=(/x-/x)x^2+0x^2.$$
This is a mess.
Perhaps starting out with a such a subtraction (on the LHS of $(1)$) here is a bad idea, since I'm trying to prove $x-x=0x^2$ after all, so it's like letting $x\mapsto x^2/x$.
So I'm stuck.

We have that:

$x−x=x+(ax)=x(1+a)+0x$

using the $4^{th}$ formula in the above list.
But $1+a=0$ by the definition of minus.
Thus, using the identity: $0x+0y=0xy$ we have:
$x−x=x(1+a)+0x=x0+0x=0x^2$.
